# Google Maps API - geocoding accuracy chart?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Where in the Google Maps API docs can I find a table explaining the `accuracy` values of Geocode lookups?

Has the range of values changed in between V2 and V3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the Google Maps API Docs. It contains a table with accuracy values...

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGeoAddressAccuracy

**Constant** | **Description**
0   Unknown location.
1   Country level accuracy.
2   Region (state, province, prefecture, etc.) level accuracy.
3   Sub-region (county, municipality, etc.) level accuracy.
4   Town (city, village) level accuracy.
5   Post code (zip code) level accuracy.
6   Street level accuracy.
7   Intersection level accuracy.
8   Address level accuracy.
9   Premise (building name, property name, shopping center, etc.) level accuracy.

Comment: I was sure I was overlooking it... the old story of the tree and the forest. Thank you!

Comment: @Pekka: Ha np, these things happen, a lot in our industry :).

Comment: Seems like the link is not valid any-more. Thanks a lot for copying the values!

Answer (score 4):

Here are the **real** status answers from `geocoder`:

You can output the `status` inside your geocoding function:

```
myMap.geocoder.geocode( 
    { address: someAdress } ), 
    function ( responses, status ) { 
        console.log( status );
    }
);
```

When passing the `status`, you can switch those four values:

```
    switch ( status )
    {
        case 'ROOFTOP' :
            var precision = 'precise';
            break;
        case 'RANGE_INTERPOLATED' :
            var precision = 'interpolated';
            break;
        case 'APPROXIMATE' :
            var precision = 'approximately';
            break;
        case 'ZERO_RESULTS' :
            var precision = 'no address';
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Is this based on version 3?

Comment: I see., for some reason I thought ROOFTOP, RANGE_INTERPOLATED, APPROXIMATE, and *ZERO_RESULTS* were part of the location_type returned by the results or (from your code) responses.?. Are those also included in the status field?

Comment: Hi Actually status shows OK, ZERO_RESULTS, OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, REQUEST_DENIED, INVALID_REQUEST, UNKNOWN_ERROR as per API docs. In V3, it is the location_type which shows ROOFTOP....

Comment: You will also get a location_type of GEOMETRIC_CENTER if you just supply an address as a road with no number say.

Answer (score 2):

@Pekka

I don't know if you saw, but V3 does not include accuracy anymore. It seems that there is a different way though. If you add the results of the address_component elements you get a similar result. Disclaimer: I am not 100% sure about this but it looks like that they included the accuracy this way. I am currently doing some testing is this the way to go.

Here an example:

I searched for: 555 Pearl Street, Boulder

Here the result with Address Level accuracy (8 levels deep).

```
        [address_component] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [long_name] => 555
                        [short_name] => 555
                        [type] => street_number
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [long_name] => Pearl St
                        [short_name] => Pearl St
                        [type] => route
                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [long_name] => Boulder
                        [short_name] => Boulder
                        [type] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => locality
                                [1] => political
                            )

                    )

                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [long_name] => Boulder
                        [short_name] => Boulder
                        [type] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => administrative_area_level_3
                                [1] => political
                            )

                    )

                [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [long_name] => Boulder
                        [short_name] => Boulder
                        [type] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                                [1] => political
                            )

                    )

                [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [long_name] => Colorado
                        [short_name] => CO
                        [type] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => administrative_area_level_1
                                [1] => political
                            )

                    )

                [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [long_name] => United States
                        [short_name] => US
                        [type] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => country
                                [1] => political
                            )

                    )

                [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [long_name] => 80302
                        [short_name] => 80302
                        [type] => postal_code
                    )

            )
```

Comment: Cheers @Paedda. I noticed that `accuracy` has gone in V3. It seems to have been replaced by a new value in the `geometrics` section (or whatever it was called, a different branch in the same XML output, I don't have the data handy) saying `ROOFTOP` when the address is perfectly encoded, and a range of other values when it's not exact, and the address components you quote.

Comment: Yeah its the 'location_type' member of the geometry section.